# Windows 7: Create keyboard shortcut that launches "repair network connection"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I want a virtual panic button for network disconnects and problems so I can press a key combination at any time and have the computer autodetect network problems or reset the adapter.

I found this on creating a keyboard shortcut:
https://lifehacker.com/5783366/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-launch-anything-in-windows

Did some digging on the network diagnostics and found
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattbie/2010/11/09/running-a-troubleshooter-from-the-command-line/

msdt.exe /id NetworkDiagnosticsWeb ==> brings up an interactive prompt. I don't want an interactive prompt, I want to bring up a tool that will start fixing the network connection ASAP with no manual intervention.

If the question remains unclear: I need to create a shortcut or batch that invokes completely automatic network repair so I can link it to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Does whatever problem that you have that gets solved with the troubleshooter also get resolved by disabling / enabling the adapter?  I think that would clear most things and should be relatively easy to script.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a batch script that will emulate the keyboard strokes to manipulate the GUI window titled "**Internet Connections**" that pops up when `msdt.exe /id NetworkDiagnosticsWeb` is run.

Essentially it will [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) the `msdt.exe /id NetworkDiagnosticsWeb` command, ensure the `Internet Connections` titled window is active, wait 2 seconds, press <kbd>`Tab`</kbd> twice, <kbd>`Enter`</kbd> once, pause 2 seconds, and then press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd> again to ensure it starts troubleshooting immediately.

[image]

[image]

---

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO OFF

start "" msdt.exe /id NetworkDiagnosticsWeb
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.AppActivate "Internet Connections"          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 2000                                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 2}{ENTER}"                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 2000                                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
- [SendKeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)
- [AppActivate](https://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html)
- [CScript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)

Comment: Is it possible to make the VBS script a static file instead of dynamically creating it via temp-file each time? Also, wouldn't the AppActivate steal focus from the currently active program? The panic button needs to do all the repair in the background without interrupting the active program.

Comment: Another dangerous thing about this solution: It generates automated key presses. If someone uses this solution to help with connectivity to an online game (which I'm sure will happen sooner or later), low-quality cheat/bot detection software might flag the scripted key commands as a bot and the end-user could be banned

Comment: This solution emulates key presses using Windows api essentially hooked in via the vbscript using all Windows native non-third party solution. If there's a game that runs on Windows that sense pressing keyboard keys is dangerous, then that implies a poor design for a game on such a platform. There is nothing dangerous about using this Windows native solution and logic to run on a Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **PowerShell** [Get-TroubleshootingPack Cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/troubleshootingpack/get-troubleshootingpack?view=win10-ps) to take you through the process of creating an answer file to later use with [Invoke-TroubleshootingPack Cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323718(v=vs.85).aspx) to automate.

---

> ### Steps: Creating and Running Manually
>
> **1. PowerShell (create answer file)**
>
> ```
> $aFile = "C:\Folder\Path\AudioAnswerFile.xml"
> Get-TroubleshootingPack -Path "C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\Networking" -AnswerFile $aFile
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Options to pick during answer file creation**
>
> **Important:** *I only picked what I think I needed to pick but do further testing and put more time and thought into each answer just in
>   case you see something applicable in your case.*
>
> - **`[1] Web Connectivity`**
> - **`[1] Troubleshoot my connection to the Internet`**
> - **`[1] TCP`**
> - **`[1] I'm trying to reach a specific website or folder on a network`**
> - Pick `[x] Exit` for all the rest of the answers and press **Enter**
>
>   [image]
>
>   [image]
>
> ---
>
> **Answer File Content**
>
> **Note:** *Now that you have an answer file, you can use it to point to jobs that you can automate or create shortcuts to run as a batch as
>   I'll talk about with more detail below.
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Answers Version="1.0">
>   <Interaction ID="IT_EntryPoint">
>     <Value>HTTP</Value>
>   </Interaction>
>   <Interaction ID="IT_WebChoice">
>     <Value>Internet</Value>
>   </Interaction>
>   <Interaction ID="IT_Protocol">
>     <Value>6</Value>
>   </Interaction>
>   <Interaction ID="IT_DefaultConnectivityInitialChoice">
>     <Value>HTTPorUNC</Value>
>   </Interaction>
> </Answers>
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **2. PowerShell (run diagnostic process)**
>
> **Note:** *The `$aFile` variable value should point to the answer file you just created in #1 above. The `$dFolder` variable value should be
>   a folder to check for the results of the diagnostic after it runs.*
>
> ```
> $aFile = "C:\Folder\Path\AudioAnswerFile.xml"
> $dFolder = "C:\Folder\Path\Diag"
> $var = Get-TroubleshootingPack -Path "C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\Networking"
> Invoke-TroubleshootingPack -Pack $v -AnswerFile $aFile -Unattended -Result $dFolder
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### Results
>
> Now open up the result files from this command you invoked with the
>   answer file by going to the folder specified in the `$dFolder`
>   variable value and you'll have some files you can further analyze.
>
> **Result Folder Files**
>
> > ```
> > 675B09EE-5DE8-4AF5-B10D-07DB894902D2.Diagnose.0.etl
> > DebugReport.xml
> > NetworkConfiguration.cab
> > ResultReport.xml
> > results.xsl
> > ```
>
> [image]

---

### Put it all in a Batch File

**Note:** *This expects the answer file to be already configured and in a readable location for the `Invoke-TroubleshootingPack` cmdlet to utilize so this is what you create with the above step #1. Other than that, you only need to set the `AnswerFile=` and the `DiagFolder=` values to be valid locations you can write to.*

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "AnswerFile=C:\Folder\Path\AudioAnswerFile.xml"
SET "DiagFolder=C:\Folder\Path\Diag"

CALL :PowerShell
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"

:PowerShell
SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpNtwkDiagTrblsht.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
ECHO $aFile = "%AnswerFile%">"%PSScript%"
ECHO $dFolder = "%DiagFolder%">>"%PSScript%"
ECHO $var = Get-TroubleshootingPack -Path "C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\Networking">>"%PSScript%"
ECHO Invoke-TroubleshootingPack -Pack $var -AnswerFile $aFile -Unattended -Result $dFolder>>"%PSScript%"
GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Further Run Validation

After this process runs you should see in the Windows **Event Viewer** of the **System** log and **Event ID `4100`** from the "Diagostics-Neworking" source with an "Information Level"  message indicating

> "*The Network Diagnostics Framework has completed the diagnosis phase
>   of operation, but no network problem was identified.*"

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Get-TroubleshootingPack Cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/troubleshootingpack/get-troubleshootingpack?view=win10-ps)
- [Invoke-TroubleshootingPack Cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323718(v=vs.85).aspx)